# Add Ajax Hooks and Call from Custom Template PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create the hooks and function for the php to receive my ajax call and when the response is alerted, all I receive is 0.

I suppose my question is, are the add_action hooks supposed to go into the bottom of the admin-ajax.php file or are they supposed to go elsewhere?  Keep in mind that my Ajax request is on a custom template .php file.

Here's the code for reference:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_ajax_action', 'my_ajax_action_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_ajax_action', 'my_ajax_action_callback' );

function my_ajax_action_callback(){

echo "Baffles";

$first_name = isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) ? $_POST['first_name'] : 'N/A';
$last_name = isset( $_POST['last_name'] ) ? $_POST['last_name'] : 'N/A';
?>
<p>Hello. Your First Name is <?php echo $first_name; ?>.</p>
<p>And your last name is <?php echo $last_name; ?>.</p>
<?php
die(); // required. to end AJAX request.

}
```

Jquery/Ajax Request

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            data: {
        action     : 'my_ajax_action', // load function hooked to: "wp_ajax_*" action hook
        first_name : 'John',           // PHP: $_POST['first_name']
        last_name  : 'Cena',           // PHP: $_POST['last_name']
        }, success: function (result) {

       alert(result);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
});

});
```

Comment: I think you're looking for the `wp_ajax_{$_REQUEST[‘action’]}` hook. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax__requestaction/ This tutorial is quite useful: https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/load-more-posts-ajax.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be here is the error

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_ajax_action', 'my_ajax_action_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_ajax_action', 'my_ajax_action_callback' );
```

change to

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_ajax_action_callback', 'my_ajax_action_callback' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_ajax_action_callback','my_ajax_action_callback' );
```

and in ajax change:

```
action : 'my_ajax_action_callback
```

go to `functions.php` and add:

```
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/custom_template.php');
```

make sure your ajax `url` is correct!!

Comment: Thanks for the input, I've actually gotten it figured out! Just dumped everything into the functions file and add the ajaxurl global shortcode to make sure that my url is correct to access admin-ajax

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's worked for me.  I'm still trying to figure out how to output the php results into an array so that they can be stored in the select element.  I'll update this when I get it figured out.

```
function add_ajaxurl_cdata_to_front(){ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php'); ?>'
</script>

<?php }
 add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_ajaxurl_cdata_to_front', 1);
 add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_js_to_wp_footer' );
  function add_js_to_wp_footer() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery("#field_6_17 select").on('change', function() {

       var product_line = jQuery(this).val();

        jQuery.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: ajaxurl,
         data: {
          "action": "view_site_description",
          first_name : 'John',           // PHP: $_POST['first_name']
          last_name  : 'Cena',
         }, success: function(data){

          console.log('product_line');
          jQuery('select#input_6_26 option').html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
<?php } 
  function view_site_description(){
  global $wpdb;

  $first_name = isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) ? $_POST['first_name'] : 'N/A';
  $last_name = isset( $_POST['last_name'] ) ? $_POST['last_name'] : 'N/A';
  ?>
  <p>Hello. Your First Name is <?php echo $first_name; ?>.</p>
  <p>And your last name is <?php echo $last_name; ?>.</p><?php

  die();
  }
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_view_site_description', 'view_site_description' );
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_view_site_description', 'view_site_description' );
```

Comment: Try `jQuery('#ID option:selected')`